# Error in contact page in Magento 2.1 site

Tags: php, magento

i am new at Magento and i need your help.
When i open the contact page on my site, i receive this error.

"We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email."

I checked the system.log file and i found that.

Could you help me ?

> [2020-11-19 14:58:18] main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Argument 2
> passed to
> Hashcrypt\Contact\Plugin\AddFieldToContactForm::afterToHtml() must be
> an instance of Hashcrypt\Contact\Plugin\string, string given, called
> in
> /var/www/vhosts/ora24.gr/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php
> on line 152 and defined in
> /var/www/vhosts/ora24.gr/httpdocs/app/code/Hashcrypt/Contact/Plugin/AddFieldToContactForm.php
> on line 20 [] []

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the system.log this error is showing at the below path:
app/code/Hashcrypt/Contact/Plugin/AddFieldToContactForm.php on line 20
Please check this or you can check by disabling this module "Hashcrypt_Contact".